Compatibility Issues with Specific NuGet Packages in .NET 7
In my .NET 7 project, I'm encountering compatibility issues with certain NuGet packages. Specifically, an older package is causing compatibility problems with the project target framework. When a package relies on a third-party JSON handler like Newtonsoft.Json instead of internal packages like System.Text.Json, I receive an error.
How can I resolve this compatibility issue in .NET 7?
Should I address this by reorganizing package dependencies in the .csproj file or with settings in global.json, or is there an alternative solution?
Can Central Package Management, which is used in .NET 7 projects, provide a solution here?
My project was upgraded from .NET 4 to .NET 7.
When I run the restore command in the package manager, I encounter compatibility errors.
Restarting the project causes version conflicts between dependent packages, and the project fails to build.
I manually adjusted package versions using dotnet add package and dotnet restore, but the errors persist.
I specified PackageReference settings in the *.csproj file and upgraded packages individually, but conflicts remain within the project.

"When a package relies on a third-party JSON handler like Newtonsoft.Json instead of internal packages like System.Text.Json, I receive an error." - well, yes, because System.Text.Json is not Newtonsoft.Json (aka JSON.NET) - nor is it a drop-in replacement: it isn't ABI nor API compatible. You'll need to either reference JSON.NET instead - or manually update all of your JSON handling C# to use STJ.
